# clicking multiple buttons in php file automatically

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello coders over there,
I have a PHP file which dynamically generates  data from database.
Each row consists of a column called status who's value is false now when the each row consists of button when clicked the value of status gets converted to true.

Now the problem here is that as my web application is growing more data is received 
so i have to manually click on button for conversion .Now is there any way to automatically press all buttons by just refreshing the page so all the data gets automatically converted so my work becomes easy .
It can be with javascript or PHP so please if anyone could help me out to carry out this operation.

Comment: Whats stopping you from setting the status to true to start with? Is there a need for this extra step if the process is going to be automated?

Comment: No need to "automatically press all buttons", when you press a button you convert the value of the row from false to true, right? So just do a script to convert all value you want from false to true. You can do an Ajax call you trigger when page load OR add ONE button to trigger ALL button at once -> when on click you convert all current row from FALSE to TRUE for example